# Second-order derivative with respect to a function of two variables.

Tags: calculus, functions, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I have a surface defined as a radius vector in spherical coordinates: $$r = r (\theta, \psi).$$ In Cartesian coordinates, the projections are calculated as follows:
$$\begin{align}
r_x &= r \sin \theta \cos \phi, \\
r_y &= r \sin \theta \sin \phi, \\
r_z &= r \cos \theta.
\end{align}$$
I want to calculate the Gaussian curvature $K$ of the surface in Cartesian coordinates expressed through spherical coordinates:
$$K=\det
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial^2 r_z}{\partial r_x^2} & \frac{\partial^2 r_z}{\partial r_x \partial r_y} \\
\frac{\partial^2 r_z}{\partial r_x \partial r_y} & \frac{\partial^2 r_z}{\partial r_y^2}
\end{pmatrix}.$$

I use the chain rule to calculate the derivatives:
$$
\begin{align}
r^{'}_x \equiv \frac{\partial r_z}{\partial r_x} &= \frac{\partial r_z}{\partial \theta} /\frac{\partial r_x}{\partial \theta} + \frac{\partial r_z}{\partial \phi} /\frac{\partial r_x}{\partial \phi},
\\
r^{'}_y \equiv\frac{\partial r_z}{\partial r_y} &= \frac{\partial r_z}{\partial \theta} /\frac{\partial r_y}{\partial \theta} + \frac{\partial r_z}{\partial \phi} /\frac{\partial r_y}{\partial \phi},
\end{align}
$$
second order derivatives are calculated in the same fashion:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial^2 r_z}{\partial r_x^2} &= \frac{\partial r^{'}_x}{\partial \theta} /\frac{\partial r_x}{\partial \theta} + \frac{\partial r^{'}_x}{\partial \phi} /\frac{\partial r_x}{\partial \phi},
\\
\frac{\partial^2 r_z}{\partial r_y \partial r_x} &= \frac{\partial r^{'}_x}{\partial \theta} /\frac{\partial r_y}{\partial \theta} + \frac{\partial r^{'}_x}{\partial \phi} /\frac{\partial r_y}{\partial \phi},
\\
\frac{\partial^2 r_z}{\partial r_x \partial r_y} &= \frac{\partial r^{'}_y}{\partial \theta} /\frac{\partial r_x}{\partial \theta} + \frac{\partial r^{'}_y}{\partial \phi} /\frac{\partial r_x}{\partial \phi},
\\
\frac{\partial^2 r_z}{\partial r_y^2} &= \frac{\partial r^{'}_y}{\partial \theta} /\frac{\partial r_y}{\partial \theta} + \frac{\partial r^{'}_y}{\partial \phi} /\frac{\partial r_y}{\partial \phi}.
\end{align}
$$
From the equation above it follows that
$$
\frac{\partial^2 r_z}{\partial r_x \partial r_y} \ne \frac{\partial^2 r_z}{\partial r_y \partial r_x},
$$
which cannot be true.

Where am I making a mistake in the reasoning above?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're considering $r_z$ as a function of two variables, either $(\theta,\phi)$ or $(r_x,r_y)$. If so, the problem is in your application of the chain rule. A correct application would be e.g.

$$
\frac{\partial r_z}{\partial r_x} = \frac{\partial r_z}{\partial \theta} \frac{\partial\theta}{\partial r_x} + \frac{\partial r_z}{\partial \phi} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r_x}\;.
$$

You seem to be under the impression that

$$
\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial r_x}=\left(\frac{\partial r_x}{\partial\theta}\right)^{-1}\;,
$$

but this is not the case. These partial derivatives need to be inverted by inverting the entire matrix of them, not individual entries of that matrix.

Comment: Ok, I see, thanks for the answer. If I understand correctly, you suggest $$ \begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial r_x} & \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r_x} \\ \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial r_y} & \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r_y}  \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial r_x}{\partial \theta} & \frac{\partial r_x}{\partial \phi} \\ \frac{\partial r_y}{\partial \theta} & \frac{\partial r_y}{\partial \phi}  \end{pmatrix}^{-\mathbf{T}} $$?

Comment: @yuriyi: Yes, in case $()^{-T}$ means the inverse transpose, that's what I mean.